# Should thank you comments flagged as too chatty be deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging

Here's an example comment on an answer.

> Thank u very much :)

It gets flagged for "too chatty"

`too chatty delete | edit | dismiss`

Moderators have seen a few of these flagged comments.  Should the comment be deleted, edited, or dismissed by moderators?

Comment: Over on Retrocomputing.SE, another young beta site, we tend to leave these comments up a week or so, then delete as *obsolete* rather than *too chatty*.

Comment: @Chenmunka Good idea and that makes sense.  Whoever is doing the flagging, using obsolete flag could be better.  I think this suggestion is good and some of these comments can be cleaned up / deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally always dismiss these type of flags. And probably I'm not following the Stack Exchange guidelines too closely by doing this.

Comments, in general are discouraged across the Stack Exchange network. However, I personally feel the need to build up a community and not a group of unrelated Q&A-posters.

Saying *Thank you!* is a nice gesture, and I appreciate that as long as people also vote up and accept helpful answers.